# How can I do wind vector plot in R?

Tags: r, vector, plot, graph, air

I have data like this:

```
date             co    pm10  wd    ws
25/10/2006 0:00  0.2    48   20  0.6
25/10/2006 1:00  0.1    32   7   0.6
25/10/2006 2:00  0.3    37   1   0.9
25/10/2006 3:00  0.2    43   3   0.9
25/10/2006 4:00  0.3    51   354 0.7
25/10/2006 5:00  0.3    42   2   1
25/10/2006 6:00  0.2    65   2   1
25/10/2006 7:00  0.7    81   1   0.8
25/10/2006 8:00  0.3    47   28  0.4
25/10/2006 9:00  0.2    39   51  0.3
25/10/2006 10:00 0.1    33   13  0.5
25/10/2006 11:00 0.1    30   24  0.3
25/10/2006 12:00 0.1    47   2   0.6
25/10/2006 13:00 0      47   4   1.1
25/10/2006 14:00 0      38   23  1.1
25/10/2006 15:00 0.1    13   56  0.8
25/10/2006 16:00 0.6    50   33  0.6
25/10/2006 17:00 0.4    26   45  0.5
25/10/2006 18:00 0.3    33   26  0.5
25/10/2006 19:00 0.6    63   17  0.8
25/10/2006 20:00 0.9    76   20  5              
25/10/2006 21:00 0.7    70   15  0.7
25/10/2006 22:00 0.4    56   14  0.9
25/10/2006 23:00 0.3    35   21  0.6
```

Then I want to create wind vectors graph like this:

[image: Example of vectors graph]

So, what should I do in R?

Comment: So what have you tried in R? Also please supply data as plain text, not images.

Comment: Sorry I am new user, now I am trying to use openair package in R but it does not has function like this. Exactly, I saw one function as calerndarplot in this package, it also use this vector also in calendarplot then I tried to see to source code of this function and I can not solve it, I have limit in R language due to beginner.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example how to draw arrows whose start points are on the x axis:

```
plot.new(); 
plot.window( xlim=c(0,21), ylim=c(-10,10)); 
arrows(1:20,0,1:20+rnorm(10),rnorm(10),length=0.08)
axis(1,pos=c(0,0))
```

There might not be a ready function for such a picture and there it is necessary to figure out how combine the whole picture line by line.